# Can't access HTML input value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I want to create a program to determine whether a given year is a leap year in the Gregorian calendar.  In the HTML file I created an `<input>` with an id, but i can't get the value in JS. Could you explain what is the problem?

```js
let year = document.getElementById("year").value;

function checkLeapYear(year) {
if ((0 == year % 4) && (0 != year % 100) || (0 == year % 400)) {
        console.log(year + ' is a leap year');
    } else {
        console.log(year + ' is not a leap year');
    }
}

checkLeapYear(year);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Enter a year: <input type="text" id = "year"> 
<input type="button" id="button" onClick="checkLeapYear()" value="Check Leap Year">
    
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that when javascript runs for the first time the `year` variable is set (in memory) to the input value (which is empty), and when entering data and pushing the button, the function `checkLeapYear` is run, but year is still empty at the time (because it is read from memory). So as @lucumt has shown, you need to get the updated input value when running the function.

Comment: It makes sense, thank you for explaining this ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `let year = document.getElementById("year").value;` is outside the `checkLeapYear()` and we have not input any value for it when this line executed

In order to solve it,you need to put `year` inside `checkLeapYear()` so that each time you can get the latest input value,also there is no need for `checkLeapYear(year);` since we have add `onClick="checkLeapYear()"`

```js
function checkLeapYear() {
let year = document.getElementById("year").value;
if ((0 == year % 4) && (0 != year % 100) || (0 == year % 400)) {
        console.log(year + ' is a leap year');
    } else {
        console.log(year + ' is not a leap year');
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    Enter a year: <input type="text" id = "year"> 
<input type="button" id="button" onClick="checkLeapYear()" value="Check Leap Year">
    
</body>
</html>
```